# Yarn installation downloads unusual folder

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, yarnpkg

I am trying to install yarn in my laptop ( Macbook Pro 2017 ) but it results in to downloading this folder /react-praktis/.

Screehshot:
[image]

I tried to run yarn install but it says - `yarn command not found`.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable <- not sure why you're trying to install yarn globally with npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like npm linked yarn from the dependancy list of one of your projects. I'd say the easiest way to install yarn on a macbook is thru homebrew.

Just run `brew update && brew install yarn`

PS: Assuming you already have homebrew installed on your macbook

Comment: hi thanks it fixed the problem. but this also happens on other dependencies like nodemon when I try to create install them they will create a /react-praktis/ folder in the htdocs.

Comment: @bbarriatos You can check the directory that yarn will install your local dependancies by running `yarn bin` in your project directory. To check the global yarn bin path, run `yarn global bin`